# More than one Asp.Net WebApplication Project in the same virtual server

Tags: asp.net

I have seen an application, which has more than one Asp.Net web application projects. It looks like the people who developed the application didn't know that they can have one Asp.Net web application project and other projects like BusinessLogic, DataLogic could have been created as C# Class Library project. What will be the implication of having all the layers as Web Application Project? Will there be any performance issue? Does each and every web application has it's own AppDomain?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Multiple projects in VS shouldn't affect performance in the application. When you build your project your references in your main website will "retrieve" the latest copy of the compiled projects. If anything this could actually improve performance on the target server since these libraries will not need to be compiled again.